# Check if define variable is exist - warning error in php

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

Hi I have the following code and get the error even if i check if the variable is exist  ,  why the php throw error?  ,
how can I check it without error

```
 if(!defined (ENV)){
     define('ENV', getenv('ENV'));
 };

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant ENV - assumed 'ENV' in  index.php on line 10
```

Comment: may the problem is **''** use that (!defined (**'ENV'**))

Comment: try !defined (ENV) to !defined ('ENV')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use quotes with the defined function. It should look like this.

```
if(!defined ('ENV')){
    define('ENV', getenv('ENV'));
};
```

And when you want to output it you can use it without quotes.

```
echo ENV;
```

Comment: ohh thx 
and when Im using the variable . its without quotes ?
echo  VAR .  ?

Comment: you defined a constant so you can echo it without quotes.